# Run separate functions on multiple elements of list based on regex criteria in data.frame

Tags: r, regex

The following works, but I'm missing a functional programming technique, indexing, or a better way of structuring my data. After a month, it will take a bit to remember exactly how this works instead of being easy to maintain. It seems like a workaround when it shouldn't be. I want to use regex to decide which function to use for expected groups of files. When a new file format comes along, I can write the read function, then add the function along with the regex to the data.frame to run it alongside all the rest.

I have different formats of Excel and csv files that need to be read in and standardized. I want to maintain a list or data.frame of the file name regex and appropriate function to use. Sometimes there will be new file formats that won't be matched, and old formats without new files. But then it gets complicated which is something I would prefer to avoid.

```
# files to read in based on filename
fileexamples <- data.frame(
  filename = c('notanyregex.xlsx','regex1today.xlsx','regex2today.xlsx','nomatch.xlsx','regex1yesterday.xlsx','regex2yesterday.xlsx','regex3yesterday.xlsx'),
  readfunctionname = NA
)

# regex and corresponding read function
filesourcelist <- read.table(header = T,stringsAsFactors = F,text = "
  greptext readfunction
 '.*regex1.*' 'readsheettype1'
 '.*nonematchthis.*' 'readsheetwrench'
 '.*regex2.*' 'readsheettype2'
 '.*regex3.*' 'readsheettype3'
 ")

# list of grepped files
fileindex <- lapply(filesourcelist$greptext,function(greptext,files){
  grepmatches <- grep(pattern = greptext,x = data.frame(files)[,1],ignore.case = T)
},files = fileexamples$filename)

# run function on files based on fileindex from grep
for(i in 1:length(fileindex)){
  fileexamples[fileindex[[i]],'readfunctionname'] <- filesourcelist$readfunction[i]
}
```